# Why is it that only the first imported module works and the rest can't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have a problem running all imported modules form a package
e.g.

```
package\
    MODULE1.py
    MODULE2.py
    MODULE3.py
    MODULE4.py
    Subpackage\
     modulea.py
     moduleb.py
```

When i import to my main program as `from package import *` (having used the `__all__`), when i run the program, only `MODULE1.py` will work and not the rest. If I change to `MODULE2.py` to be the first, it works and not the rest.

How do I fix this?
Hey pepr I seem to have run to a brick wall. My code is for a game for children to play with. I managed to come with the code as follows:

```
import re
import sys
name = input
name = input('Please Enter your question: ').lower()
name2 - name[:]
    for item in name2:
    if len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE1
    elif len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE2
    elif len(name2) >=3:
     MODULE3............# CONTINUES LIKE THIS FOR THESE MODULES
```

Sample MODULES
MODULE1

```
import re
import sys
name = input
name = input(Please Enter your question: ').lower
name2 = name[:]
colorLists = ['what is my color', 'color', ...]# this list have about 5mb of sample lists.Other lists have items for foods, cars, toys etc
for item in name2:
    if item in name2 and in colorLists:
     print('you found the color here')
     name3 = input('What is your favorite color?')
     if name3 == red:
      print('You are hot!')
     elif name3 == pink:
      print('You must be a lady')
     elif name3 == blue:
      print('Boys love this')
     elif....#continues with as many colors as possible
```

Modules 2,3,4,etc have different games for say cars, homes, foods, toys, etc
So back to the same question above, once I import MODULES, ONLY the first module runs. I want it to work in a way that it will jump to MODULE2 if the question is not in MODULE1.
Once more, am new to Python and your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you using `__all__` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let the `package` subdir contains `__init__.py` with:

```
from .Subpackage import *
__all__ = ['MODULE1', 'MODULE2', 'MODULE3', 'MODULE4',
           'modulea', 'moduleb']
print('Package', __name__, 'imports', __all__)
```

Notice the first line that imports all modules from `Subpackage` subdir. However, it is not what you usually want -- here for simplicity. Let the `MODULE1.py`, `MODULE2.py`,  `MODULE3.py`, and  `MODULE4.py` contain the same code:

```
def f():
    return __name__

print('Module', __name__, 'imported')
```

Let the `Subpackage` contains the followint `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['modulea', 'moduleb']
print('Package', __name__, 'imports', __all__)
```

and the `modulea.py` and `moduleb.py` contain the same code as the above modules:

```
def f():
    return __name__

print('Module', __name__, 'imported')
```

(i.e. just copy the module files and give it the names.)

Now, try the following example, `a.py` that contains:

```
#!python3
from package import *

print('-------------------')
print(MODULE1.f())
print(MODULE2.f())
print(MODULE3.f())
print(MODULE4.f())
print(modulea.f())
print(moduleb.f())
```

After launching `py a.py`, you should observe the following:

```
c:\_Python\wakamdr\so20824045>py a.py
Package package.Subpackage imports ['modulea', 'moduleb']
Module package.Subpackage.modulea imported
Module package.Subpackage.moduleb imported
Package package imports ['MODULE1', 'MODULE2', 'MODULE3', 'MODULE4', 'modulea',
'moduleb']
Module package.MODULE1 imported
Module package.MODULE2 imported
Module package.MODULE3 imported
Module package.MODULE4 imported
-------------------
package.MODULE1
package.MODULE2
package.MODULE3
package.MODULE4
package.Subpackage.modulea
package.Subpackage.moduleb
```

Notice the order of the imported modules. Notice also that module names case matters.

Comment: Imports are not the problem here

Comment: Why the downvote? It was the attempt to explain how the `__all__` can be used and tested. Notice that the anwer written befor the question was edited.

Comment: @pepr Because your beautiful (no sarcasm) explanation does not answer the question why the code did not work.

Comment: Did you check how the question looked at the time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in imports - rather in the structure of your code.
While you iterate over letters in the string *name2*, you always check **only** the length of *name2* against the **same** condition. Thus **you always enter only the first *if* clause**. *import*, obviously, works as it is - the logic of the code that is wrong. Just reread this block

```
for item in name2:
    if len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE1
    elif len(name2) >= 3:
     MODULE2
    elif len(name2) >=3:
     MODULE3............# CONTINUES LIKE THIS FOR THESE MODULES
```

Comment: Thanks @volcano, i will evaluate and respond.